# How to exclude a host from a "task" in playbook, I'm gonna get "host name" from the user as a parameter while running playbook

Tags: ansible

Basically, I have 6 nodes on inventory host list, which I want to stop a service on 5 hosts at a time and one at last. 
And that one last host is not going to be the same every time and I'm asking user to enter that hostname as a parameter while triggering playbook.

This is what I did but "!" is not working in delegate_to option.

```
- name: Action on processor - stop
  shell: ./all.ksh "{{ Action }}"
  args:
   chdir: "/local"
  register: action_result_stop_inactive
  #delegate_to: UAT:!"{{ active_server }}"
  when: parameter == "stop"
  notify:
   - "If action is to stop the service"

- name: Action on processor - stop
  shell: ./all.ksh "{{ Action }}"
  args:
   chdir: "/local"
  register: action_result_stop_active
  delegate_to: "{{ active_server }}"
  when: parameter == "stop"
  notify:
   - "If action is to stop the service"

- name: Action on processor - status, start, restart
  shell: ./all.ksh "{{ Action }}"
  args:
   chdir: "/local"
  register: action_result
  when: parameter == "status" or parameter == "start" or parameter == "restart"
  notify:
   - "if action is status or start or restart"
```

handlers:

```
- name: If action is to start service or to query status of service
  debug:
    msg: "{{ action_result.stdout }}"
  when: action_result is defined
  listen:
   - "if action is status or start or restart"

- name: If action is to stop the service
  debug:
    msg: "Stop service: {{item}}"
  with_items:
   - "{{ action_result_stop_inactive.stdout }}"
   - "{{ action_result_stop_active.stdout }}"
  when: action_result_stop_inactive is defined or action_result_stop_active is defined
  listen:
   - "If action is to stop the service"
```

I'm trying to execute ./all.ksh stop on all nodes that are in hosts list except the "active_consumer" node (which is also part of hosts list)in one go
and
then to execute ./all.ksh stop on "active_consumer" node

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way to do this would be to append to your when conditional.  If 'active_server' is the one that you are having the end user supply at the command line, you could change your when to this:

`when: parameter == "stop" and inventory_hostname != active_server`

And then on your next task change it to this:

`when: parameter == "stop" and inventory_hostname == active_server`

Also, you only need that delegeate_to line if you are trying to run the task on something other than the host that you currently on in your inventory.  So in your example, that second delegate_to command would run the same command on the 'active_server' 6 times.  So unless that is what you are trying to do, you can just leave that line out.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to stop a service on 5 hosts at a time and one at last

Easy, you can use `serial` command, it will run through your inventory 5 hosts at time:

```
- hosts: '{{ inventory }}'
  serial: 5
  tasks:
  - name: Action on processor - stop
```

The `one at last` you can use `delegate_to` and use an external variable or `set_fact` like `{{ singe_host }}`. Than in your code you can manipulate it as needed.